# how to download data as DataFrame, from known figure to two different directions

Tags: python, pandas

How can i write a program to download DataFrame from "Known number" (option strike price) such as 20?
I want to download data from 19 to 14 (each step 1) and from 20 to 30 (each step 1).

**I am not interested in all strike prices.**

I am not programmer, so i don't have any idea how to begin.
Please see:

[Attached file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOZzR.jpg)

Hi Again,
Thanks for your help, it was very useful.
I managed to understand a little something, and write the following code:

```
from pandas_datareader.data import Options
import pandas as pd

pd.set_option('display.width',280) # default is 80

symbol = Options('aapl', 'yahoo')

Call_this_week =symbol.get_near_stock_price(expiry=symbol.expiry_dates[0:1])
Call_this_week.iloc[0:5:, 0:5]
print(Call_this_week)

Call_2nd_week = symbol.get_near_stock_price(expiry=symbol.expiry_dates[1:2])
Call_2nd_week.iloc[0:5:, 0:5]
print(Call_2nd_week)

Call_3rd_week = symbol.get_near_stock_price(expiry=symbol.expiry_dates[2:3])
Call_3rd_week.iloc[0:5:, 0:5]
print(Call_3rd_week)
```

And i got these results:

[My Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHXt7.jpg)

Now, i have two more questions:
1. How can i get more strikes, on each Expiry date (such as: 140, 145, 150, 155, 160....**i got strikes from 165 to 175 only**....to 180, 185, 190, 195, 200)?
2. I have "CALL" options only. How can i get "PUT" options also?

Thanks and have a nice day.

Comment: you could start here:  https://pandas-datareader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Does anyone have any more ideas?